# Does git reuse blobs?

Tags: git, version-control

Let's say I committed a binary file, then changed it a couple of commits later and now I changed it back in a new commit.

Out of curiosity, I wondered if git creates a new blob for it? Or does it detect it's in the history and reuse it? If so, how does it detect that? Checksum?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Git will reuse the same blob.

I have done a test. I made 3 commits. First I commit a binary file, then I modified the binary file and commit it again. Then finally I overwrote the file by original binary used in the first commit and commit again.

The binary files content in 1st & 3rd commits are the same. Each commit is the HEAD of the follow branches:

1st commit: "FIRST". 2nd commit: "SECOND". 3rd commit: "master"

Then if you run "git cat-file -p FIRST^{tree}" , it shows hash code of the binary file.

```
$ git cat-file -p FIRST^{tree}
100644 blob ec049240a47b472bd7c31d1fa27118c4fe2f1229    test.db3
$ git cat-file -p SECOND^{tree}
100644 blob a47bb3727e5aefe3ec386bec5520f3e4ffb3a4c5    test.db3
$ git cat-file -p master^{tree}
100644 blob ec049240a47b472bd7c31d1fa27118c4fe2f1229    test.db3
```

You will find that the hash code of the blob of 1st and 3rd commit are the same.

git is so smart enough to check whether a blob exists for a hash code and reuse that blob if found.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  The key here is that the SHA1 is, well, the "key" to the file, in terms of a key/value database, that is.  The SHA1 is a cryptographic checksum of the contents of the file (plus some unique-ifying stuff and size information).  Two identical files will compute the same checksum, and thus store one single git object, whose name is the SHA-1 checksum.  It does not matter when the checksum is computed, only whether a file that has that checksum-as-name is in the repository.

Comment: @torek: Exactly. Internally, a git repo is more or less a key-value database. The keys are the SHA1 checksums of the git objects (commits, trees, blobs and tags), and the value is the corresponding object. The reuse of blobs (and trees) is an automatic consequence of this structure.